# Converstion to ARC reports semantic Issue Instance method 'window' not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am converting an objective-C OSX project which is manual memory managed, to ARC.
For that I selected the project  -> Edit -> Convert -> To Objective-C ARC.

The I get several errrors and I am solving them one by one. Below is an error shown as Semantic issue. that I do not understand.

`Semantic Issue, AppController.m:263:21: Instance method 'window' not found ; did you mean 'windows'?` 
`Warning: AppController.m:263:21: Instance method '-window' not found (return type defaults to 'id'); did you mean '-windows'?`

The code is below

```
[[[NSApp delegate] window] setTitle:winTitle];
```

The AppDelegate does have a window property, I am not sure, why is xcode complaining about it.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "AppController.h"
#import "UpdateWindowController.h"


@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSWindow* _window;
    AppController* _appController;
    UpdateWindowController* updateWinController;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet AppController *appController;



@end
```

Comment: Cast the delegate to your subclass `[[(AppDelegate*)[NSApp delegate] window] setTitle:winTitle];`?

Comment: @trojanfoe that was helpful, thank you

Comment: in your implementation is there any @synthesize window = _window; ?